# What are .NET classes to replace the old MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to migrate an old project from VbScript to C# and even if I can use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP adding a reference, I wish to replace it with a newer native class  in .NET. What are the options?

This is the kind of request in VbScript I have to replace to send an XML request and receive XML in response:

```
Set xml1 = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xml1.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", False
xml1.Async = False
xml1.Loadxml xmlrqst

Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
XMLhttp.Open "POST", "https://weblink.tsdasp.net/10715xml.asp", False
XMLhttp.Send xml1.xml

Set xmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.loadXML XMLhttp.responseText
Set objLst = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Message")
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the kind of requests you were doing before with ServerXMLHTTP? I think you could use HttpClient, or HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse

Comment: I just edit the question and locate in it the code of the VbScript request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic GET/POST HTTP Requests, you can use the `WebClient` class, or the newer `HttpClient`.

For XML, you can use the `XmlDocument` class or `XDocument`.  The XmlDocument class can even load documents via HTTP by itself.

Comment: For additional information check the following article: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/330589]. It provides example code in VB6 and .NET comparing typical tasks in both platforms.